# Acessing property from blade view laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Im trying to show some data in my view and ONLY the `id` property is getting changed to some random number when its passed to the view. The other properties are okay.

If I try to access a property from a view like this: `{{ dd($var[1]) }}`, it works and I can see the id like this:

[image]

But if I try to access passing the id directly: `{{ dd($var[1]['id']) }}` or `{{ dd($var[1]->id) }}`, I just get this:

[image]

And here are some more examples from what I get accessing it directly:

[image]

If I use `gettype()` is this var I get `Integer` back, but it is actually a `string` as you can see in the first printscreen.

Why is my blade view doing this? And how can I fix it?

Comment: What does `$var` contain ? Any code that would clarify that part would help us investigate.

Comment: how about {{ dd($var[1][0]) }}

Comment: `$var` is an `array of arrays`, and each array has `id` property

Comment: If I try `{{ dd($var[1][0]) }}` i get `null` for all the properties, not only `id`

Comment: Can you share controller code while passing this value to view. Also, can you add model code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using another id I was receiving in the same array, looks like blade was decoding the string or something like that. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score -1):

in your controller please select id as new_id and try to print

```
$var[1]->new_id or $var[1]['new_id']
```

it will fix your problem
if fixed give a green tick and a thumbs up else leave a commetn will try to update you